# Skpsmtpmessage API

Tags: ios, api, appstore-approval

My application need to send mail on background without display any mail compose screen so i got suggestion as skpsmtpmessage api .shall i use this api for my application and any apple rejection by using this api.I am new to ios application development so tell me the way to use third party api in applicatiion without apple rejection.can any one help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sudha and MarJamRob answered, your app can be rejected if you are sending mails in  background but there is a workaround to this.

You can create a web method which takes the mail ids and content to be mailed as inputs and mails to the intended email ids. Call this method from within your iOS app with appropriate parameters. In this way you can fulfill your purpose without a risk of rejection as your app is not mailing in background but you are only giving a call to remote method!

Answer (score 0):

You will get an Apple rejection for sending background e-mail without using the compose screen, or an in-app compose screen (g-mail).

Comment: thanks...please tell me how can i send mail in background by button click in alert view without accessing remote servers

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  your application will be rejected from apple because it is illegal to sending background email without display mail compose screen or without user interaction ...
...